# confused terms: cover index, compound index and multi-fields index

Tags: database, indexing

I am confused with these 3 terms: cover index, compound index and multi-fields index.

Are they same things? or each of them has subtle difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Compound index** and **multi-fields Index** are the same. Other terms for the same are **Multi-Column Index** and **Concatenated Index**.

  That are indexes that contain more than one column.
- I suspect that **Cover Index** is actually **Covering Index** which is something entirely different, better described as **Index-Only-Scan**.

  That is **not** a property of an index, it is describing how the index is used. It means that a particular query can be satisfied with data from the index only, not needing to read the table data. (Note: An index copies data from the table).

  A single index can be a covering-index for one query, but not cover another query (that accesses columns not included (**covered**) in the index). Think of "The index **covers** the entire query."

More about database indexing: http://use-the-index-luke.com/